# How to update DataGrid items automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, selectionchanged

I have a DataGrid whose items can be edited by external ComboBoxes and TextBoxes (that is, the DataGrid SelectedItem is binded whith the same object as ComboBoxes and TextBoxes).

When I edit an Item in the external TextBlock the DataGrid selected item updates automatically. However when I edit an Item using the external comboboxes the DataGrid doesn't update.

I tried using the following methods when SelectionChanged event is triggered, but it didn't work.

```
MyDataGrid.CommitEdit();
MyDataGrid.CancelEdit();
MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Any idea?

Comment: show your `comboBox` codes

Answer (score 0):

try to use the textbox events to trigger it, when the data is edited by them it will put it back in its place. or use a buttom